# Why can't I write cout<<a==b; but can write cout<<(a==b);

Tags: c++, syntax-error

I know `()` has higher precedence than `<<`, and `<<` has higher precedence than `==`, but I want to know why I can't write `cout<<a==b;` yet can write `cout<<(a==b);` in C++.

How the compiler translates `cout<<a==b;` and then shows error?

Comment: Did you try? What happened?

Comment: You need to take more care with making things visible as you are seeing them to ask about them. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: `<<` has higher precedence than `==` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @Yunnosch - By all means, please do. I feel I've done all I can.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: @StoryTeller Your wish is my command. Now point out my mistakes, for balancing. ;-)

Comment: @StoryTeller Well, next time then. It is not too hard to catch me at errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<<` has higher precedence than `==` 
as you can see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

The statement

```
cout<<a==b
```

is equivalent to

```
(cout<<a)==b
```

The expression

```
cout<<a
```

returns a stream. This stream is compared to `b`. If there is no left shift operator for a stream and `a` or no comparing operator for a stream and `b` this causes a compiler error

Answer (score 2):

`cout<<a==b` is similar to `(cout<<a) == b` as `<<` has higher precedence over `==`. Now `cout<<a` will be syntactically incorrect if the type of `a` is not supported for `<<`. Next, if `a` has an overload for the `<< operator`, it will again be syntactically wrong as the `==` operator can't operate with `std::stream` and type of `b` unless `b` overloads this compare operator.

But in case of `cout<<(a==b)`, `a==b` will result in a `boolean` value. As the `<<` operator support `boolean` value it is a valid operation.

Answer (score 1):

`<<` priority is higher than `==` so it's interpreted as `(cout<<a)==b`

but `=` has lower so you can do :

`bool t = a == b`

Comment: *writing cout<<a==b is interpreted as (cout<<a)==b*. True. However, what's wrong with `(cout<<a)==b`? Why would that not compile?

Comment: ```(cout<<a)``` is not the same type as ```b```.

You can do

```while(cout << a)```

which means if ```cout``` returns fail then the loop stops

but it's ***not a boolean expression*** and it's not converted implicitly so you have to do explicit conversion ```bool t = (bool) (cout << a)```

Comment: I sort of follow your logic. However, you might want to see [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58357770/10957435) to see what I'm trying to get at.